# iOS , iPhone Snapshot in background/foreground transition

Tags: ios, background, snapshot, background-foreground

When an iOS application changes the state from foreground to background the OS takes the snapshot of the current view(screen) and when it again comes to foreground it displays that snapshot.
Is there any way (animation or anything)to intercept that snapshot and display any custom image when the application comes to foreground from background?

Note:
I dont want to take a snapshot of any view, I just want to display any custom image when the application enters to foreground from background, to make it more clear, whatever snapshot the OS displays while coming to foreground from background, I want to replace that snapshot with my custom image,The behavior I want would be "whenever the transition happens from background to foreground, the application will display my custom image every time, irrespective of the view from which it entered in the background." Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2):

You can register for the `UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification` notification and display the image you want to present then.

Answer (score 1):

There are two delegate methods available in AppDelegate itself:

```
 - applicationDidEnterBackground
 - applicationWillEnterForeground
```

For more details about this method, refer [UIApplicationDelegate class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

So using these two methods you can find the events, where you require to take a snapshot and the other where you display that image.

Now, how to take a snapshot of your view, so here is a code snippet for that:

```
    // define the frame as per your requirement
    CGRect contextRect  = CGRectMake(0, 0, myView.frame.size.width, 
                                   myView.frame.size.height); 
  // whatever you need

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(contextRect.size);  

    [myView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

  UIImage* viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

`viewImage` is the object which contains the screenshot image of your screen. So display this image in an UIImageView in `applicationWillEnterForeground` method.

Hope this will help you to solve your problem

Comment: I dont want to take a snapshot of any view, I just want to display any custom image when the application enters to foreground from background, to make it more clear, whatever snapshot the OS displays while coming to foreground from background, I want to replace that snapshot with my custom image,The behavior I want would be "whenever the transition happens from background to foreground, the application will display my custom image every time, irrespective of the view from which it entered in the background." Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Then implement your code in applicationWillEnterForeground method available in AppDelegate class